# Creating Seq after waiting for all results from map/foreach in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to loop over inputs and process them to produce scores.
Just for the first input, I want to do some processing that takes a while.
The function ends up returning just the values from the 'else' part. The 'if' part is done executing after the function returns the value.
I am new to Scala and understand the behavior but not sure how to fix it.
I've tried inputs.zipWithIndex.map instead of foreach but the result is the same.

```scala
def getscores(
    inputs: inputs
): Future[Seq[scoreInfo]] = {
  var scores: Seq[scoreInfo] = Seq()
  inputs.zipWithIndex.foreach {
    case (f, i) => {
      if (i == 0) {
        // long operation that returns Future[Option[scoreInfo]]
        getgeoscore(f).foreach(gso => { 
          gso.foreach(score => {
            scores = scores.:+(score)
          })
        })
      } else {
        scores = scores.:+(
          scoreInfo(
            id = "",
            score = 5
          )
        )
      }
    }
  }
  Future {
    scores
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you need, I would drop the mutable variable and replace `foreach` with `map` to obtain an immutable list of Futures and `recover` to handle exceptions, followed by a [`sequence`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#sequence[A,CC[X]%3C:IterableOnce[X],To](in:CC[scala.concurrent.Future[A]])(implicitbf:scala.collection.BuildFrom[CC[scala.concurrent.Future[A]],A,To],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[To]) like below:

```
def getScores(inputs: Inputs): Future[List[ScoreInfo]] = Future.sequence(
  inputs.zipWithIndex.map{ case (input, idx) =>
    if (idx == 0)
      getGeoScore(input).map(_.getOrElse(defaultScore)).recover{ case e => errorHandling(e) }
    else
      Future.successful(ScoreInfo("", 5))
  })
```

To capture/print the result, one way is to use `onComplete`:

```
getScores(inputs).onComplete(println)
```

Comment: It would be better to use `Future.traverse`

Comment: @Luis, I liked the idea, but didn't like in this case that the function for `traverse` would need to take also the collection index.

Answer (score 1):

The part your missing is understanding a tricky element of concurrency, and that is that the order of execution when using multiple futures is not guaranteed. 
If your block here is long running, it will take a while before appending the score to `scores`

```scala
// long operation that returns Future[Option[scoreInfo]]
        getgeoscore(f).foreach(gso => { 
          gso.foreach(score => {
            // stick a println("here") in here to see what happens, for demonstration purposes only
            scores = scores.:+(score)
          })
        })
```

Since that executes concurrently, your `getscores` function will also simultaneously continue its work iterating over the rest of `inputs` in your `zipWithindex`. This iteration, especially since it's trivial work, likely finishes well before the long-running `getgeoscore(f)` completes the execution of the `Future` it scheduled, and the code will exit the function, moving on to whatever code is next after you called `getscores`

```scala
val futureScores: Future[Seq[scoreInfo]] = getScores(inputs)
futureScores.onComplete{
  case Success(scoreInfoSeq) => println(s"Here's the scores: ${scoreInfoSeq.mkString(",")}"

}
//a this point the call to getgeoscore(f) could still be running and finish later, but you will never know

doSomeOtherWork()
```

Now to clean this up, since you can run a `zipWithIndex` on your `inputs` parameter, I assume you mean it's something like a `inputs:Seq[Input]`. If all you want to do is operate on the first input, then use the `head` function to *only* retrieve the first option, so `getgeoscores(inputs.head)` , you don't need the rest of the code you have there.

Also, as a note, if using Scala, get out of the habit of using mutable `var`s, *especially* if you're working with concurrency. Scala is built around supporting immutability, so if you find yourself wanting to use a `var` , try using a `val` and look up how to work with the Scala's collection library to make it work.

Comment: Thank you, that cleared things up nicely and I will keep your note about `var` in mind.

Answer (score 0):

In general, that is when you have several concurrent futures, I would say Leo's answer describes the right way to do it. However, you want only the first element transformed by a long running operation. So you can use the future return by the respective function and append the other elements when the long running call returns by mapping the future result:

```
def getscores(inputs: Inputs): Future[Seq[ScoreInfo]] = 
    getgeoscore(inputs.head)
        .map { optInfo => 
            optInfo ++ inputs.tail.map(_ => scoreInfo(id = "", score = 5))
        }
```

So you neither need `zipWithIndex` nor do you need an additional future or join the results of several futures with `sequence`. Mapping the future just gives you a new future with the result transformed by the function passed to `.map()`.